# Linux server module load issue

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bioinformatics, environment-modules

I work with Linux server and if I load by shell script module its not available.

This is shell script

```
source /cvmfs/software.xxxx.yyyyy/modulefiles/5.1.0/loadmodules
module add unicycler-0.5.0
module add pymol

module list 

unicycler --help
```

This is the output (line 20 doesn't fit because here isn't qsub settings as in the original script)

```
Loading unicycler/0.5.0
  Loading requirement: intelcdk/17.1 htslib/1.9 samtools/1.9 blast/2.7.1
    bowtie2/2.3.5.1 gcc/8.3.0 glibc/2.27 spades/3.15.4 racon/1.4.3
    pilon/1.22-intel-19.0.4-6enqoaq ale/1
Currently Loaded Modulefiles:
 1) metabase/1             8) glibc/2.27 <aL>                       
 2) intelcdk/17.1 <aL>     9) spades/3.15.4 <aL>                    
 3) htslib/1.9 <aL>       10) racon/1.4.3 <aL>                      
 4) samtools/1.9 <aL>     11) pilon/1.22-intel-19.0.4-6enqoaq <aL>  
 5) blast/2.7.1 <aL>      12) ale/1 <aL>                            
 6) bowtie2/2.3.5.1 <aL>  13) unicycler/0.5.0                       
 7) gcc/8.3.0 <aL>        14) pymol/2.3.4                           

Key:
<module-tag>  <aL>=auto-loaded  
/var/spool/pbs/mom_priv/jobs/14831393.xxxx.yyyyy.zzzz.SC: line 20: unicycler: command not found
```

Why do I get this error even though unicycler has been loaded?

I tried many modifications and different paths. Others modules work fine. And also if I connect to machine directly, I can reach the unicycler module but not from script.

Comment: I think, you do have `unicycler` in your PATH, because the error message comes from the file `/var/spool/pbs/mom_priv/jobs/14831393.xxxx.yyyyy.zzzz.SC` (line 20) and not from your script (which has much less lines). Could it be that you are not showing us all relevant parts of your script?

Comment: Note that `module` is not part of bash itself; the only module system bash comes with is one for loading and unloading C extensions. When your question revolves around 3rd-party components, be sure to name them / point out where they come from.

Comment: yeah and there is also some qsub specifications. Is it important? Also shouldn't it be same path if there is module list with unicycler ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before running `unicycler` command, you can output the content of the `unicycler/0.5.0` module with:

```
module show unicycler/0.5.0
```

This module should append the unicycler's bin directory to the `PATH` environment variable. You should find in the output of the previous command something like:

```
prepend-path PATH /path/to/unicycler-0.5.0/bin
```

If the `unicycler/0.5.0` module does not alter the `PATH` environment variable, this is why `unicycler` command is not found. Module file should be updated to add binary directory to `PATH`.

If `unicycler/0.5.0` module adds a directory to `PATH`, check this directory exists and contains the `unicycler` command